# jQuery autocomplete in ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms

Has anyone used jQuery to populate an autocomplete list on a textbox using ASP.NET webforms? If so, can anyone recommend a good method? From my reading so far, it seems like most people are using delimited lists rather than JSON to bring the items back. I'm open to any ideas that will get me up and running rather quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many examples on the web. I've used this one before, and if I recall you only need to create an aspx that will return matching terms as a `<BR/>` separated list:

http://www.dyve.net/jquery/?autocomplete

The documentation shows php in the example, but there's no difference in the way the plugin itself works and I didn't have to do anything special as a result.

From the documentation:

```
> $("#input_box").autocomplete("my_autocomplete_backend.php");
```

> In the above example, Autocomplete
>   expects an input element with the id
>   "input_box" to exist. When a user
>   starts typing in the input box, the
>   autocompleter will request
>   my_autocomplete_backend.php with a GET
>   parameter named q that contains the
>   current value of the input box. Let's
>   assume that the user has typed
>   "foo"(without quotes). Autocomplete
>   will then request
>   my_autocomplete_backend.php?q=foo.
>
> The backend should output possible
>   values for the autocompleter, each on
>   a single line. Output cannot contain
>   the pipe symbol "|", since that is
>   considered a separator (more on that
>   later).
>
> An appropiate simple output would be:
>   foo 
>   fool 
>   foot 
>   footloose 
>   foo fighters
>   food fight

Comment: I had run across this one before, but was just wondering if there were any other commonly used plugins. This one works great, though. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

I made a tutorial to do this with asp.net mvc but it should be almost identical for traditional webforms:

http://blogs.msdn.com/joecar/archive/2009/01/08/autocomplete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Asp.Net WebControl and some Asp.Net MVC extension methods wrapping the JQuery UI autocomplete widget.

I wrote documentation as well about how to implement a working resource providing a JSon result.

You can find it at:

http://autocompletedotnet.codeplex.com/

Hope it can help