# jQuery Postback with Webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

We're redevloping a major section of our website and rather than use a 90k AJAX file I'd rather use a 19K jquery script.

I've seen the following articles;

- [Using jQuery for AJAX with ASP.NET
  Webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202538/using-jquery-for-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms)
- [jQuery autocomplete in ASP.NET webforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240721/jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net-webforms)
- [Autocomplete with ASP.Net MVC and
  JQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/joecar/archive/2009/01/08/autocomplete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery.aspx)

The thing I don't get is how to do a postback to a specific method in either the code behind or another class.

I know in ASP.NET-MVC I can post back to a controller / action.  How do I call a particular method in WebForms?

Something along the lines of; $.post("*class and action*", ( *param:value*}......

Any thoughts, code etc???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy to call specific methods in code-behind. [Here is nice article](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) with all the details by Dave.

Simply declare a method like this:

```
 [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
```

This is all you need in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg, status, xhr) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

*Caveats:*

1. `WebMethod` must be on a static method
2. Must stringify posted data if sending anything (i.e. `JSON.stringify(yourDataObject)`), will be deserialized according to method parameters
3. `msg` is the response, the return result from your method is in the property `msg.d`

Comment: Dang! Blocked by our company internet filter which blocks most useful development sites.  Will check from home tonight thank you @TheVillageIdiot.  Great name btw.