# Searchfield with autocomplete ASP.NET and Database

Tags: asp.net, jquery, database, search, autocomplete

## Searchfield with autocomplete

I would like to make a searchfield with autocomplete, so when you write like 2 or 3 letters it will show a dropdownlist with results that match a column from a table in the database.

I have been reading all over the internet, and i have found out that it can be done with jQuery and AJAX Control Toolkit.
But i don't know how to make it compare the search textbox and the database and show results that match?

### UPDATE:

I have been trying to make it work with Autocomplete extender from Ajax control toolkit, but i don't know how to make the Webservice with SQL.

### UPDATE2

Can't get the webservice to work, so have been looking at jQuery UI, which can do autocomplete but don't know how to get that working with the database either.. :p

### UPDATE3

I'm still stuck on this, so if anyone who knows how to make a **datasource(webservice)** that works with either Autocomplete extender or jQuery UI, please help me.

*I want the autocomplete to show: `SELECT * FROM TABEL WHERE Title LIKE + '%' @Search + '%'` And its an MSSQL Database*

Comment: Your best bet is to create a web service that you use to interact with. Here is a pretty detailed SO post on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240721/jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net-webforms

Comment: Even with jQuery UI you will need some form of datasource. You have not provided enough info on you DB schema to help in that regards.

Comment: I want the autocomplete to show: SELECT * FROM TABEL WHERE Title LIKE + '%' @Search + '%'. And its an MSSQL Database.

Comment: Side note: That query will require a full index/table scan on each invocation. Depending on the table size, you might want to look into fulltext indexes and operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Asp.net Ajax control toolkit.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

The database can be searched as shown below.

```
select * from tbl_Country where countryName like '%xxx%'
```

You can call sql statement from a Service method. Service method can be a web service.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="autoComplete1" 
    TargetControlID="myTextBox"
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
    ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Create an asmx web service in your web application named AutoComplete.asmx. Then create a web method GetCompletionList. Inside this method you can include System.Data.SqlClient and fire the query to the database.

Comment: Yes i know, but how do i get it to show results from the database?

Comment: How do you use a SQL Statement together with an Autocomplete extender?

Comment: How do i make the web service with SQL Statement then? :p

Comment: I have been looking at several different tutorials on how to make the webservice for autocomplete but can't really get it work..